# Fast parse string to other types provided at run time?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build a faster version of `Convert.ChangeType`. The type is provided at run-time. The function is used to parse the strings from **text files**, etc.

```
public static object ConvertTo(Type t, string s)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s) || s == null || Convert.IsDBNull(s)) return null;
    if (t == typeof(string)) return s; 
    if (t == typeof(DateTime)) { .... /* parse and return it */ }
    if (t == typeof(int)) { return int.Parse(s); }
    ....
    return Convert.ChangeType(s, t, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); // Slowest
}
```

However, it's still slowest part in the profiling. Is it a way to improve the speed faster?

Comment: Try to use some keyed collection to store conversion functions, like `Dictionary<Type, Func<Object, String>>` of  analogous `HashTable`.

Comment: This is why you should avoid the situation in the first place.  It's an inherently expensive problem to begin with, converting something to a type not known at compile time.  You should very, very rarely be in such a situation.  You should, in most all situations, know the type that you want at compile time.  Also keep in mind if there were just some silver bullet to solve this problem don't you think that would be used as the definition of `Convert.ChangeType`?

Comment: @EugenePodskal With only a handful of types it's unlikely to make a meaningful difference.  He'd have to have several dozen, if not hundreds, of types for that to even start to matter.

Comment: You could also do a `switch` on `Type.GetTypeCode(t)` to reduce branching, at least for the most common system types.  But I would heed Servy's advice.

Comment: @Servy Probably yes, maybe it is the actual conversion that really takes a heavy toll on performance, but in that case there is nothing to be done other than some completely different approach to the problem.

Comment: @EugenePodskal You're quite right that there isn't really anything to be done.  [That's what I said myself](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673719/fast-parse-string-to-other-types-provided-at-run-time#comment40122553_25673719).

Comment: This may be too heavyweight for what you are trying to achieve, but take a look at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/61460/Using-LINQ-for-type-conversion), it presents a tricky but fast (in terms of amortized cost) way of converting between types.

Comment: how many if's are there and how many possible target types? Slowest compared to what measure? Is it **critically** slow? or just slower than everything else? There is definetly some most expensive type, casting to which affects most. Try to figure this boy and try to invent some workaround for it. Personally I don't see how `string` to `int` or to `DateTime` conversion can result in the perf-critical issue, so there's **something else** in your code than is not shown.

Comment: The slowest part about this is the fact you're converting a string to another type.  If this was my code I would look at my options in terms of input.  All `Convert.ChangeType` is doing is using `IConvertable` for a small set of common types.  So you could write a much faster custom implementation for something other than string.

Answer (score 1):

Converting a string to another type is inherently expensive.  But, `Convert.ChangeType` is doing a virtual interface call and boxing/unboxing that you can avoid.

Here's what it's doing under the covers:

```
public static object ChangeType(object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
{
  if (conversionType == (Type) null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("conversionType");
  if (value == null)
  {
    if (conversionType.IsValueType)
      throw new InvalidCastException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_CannotCastNullToValueType"));
    else
      return (object) null;
  }
  else
  {
    IConvertible convertible = value as IConvertible;
    if (convertible == null)
    {
      if (value.GetType() == conversionType)
        return value;
      else
        throw new InvalidCastException(Environment.GetResourceString("InvalidCast_IConvertible"));
    }
    else
    {
      RuntimeType runtimeType = conversionType as RuntimeType;
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[3])
        return (object) (bool) (convertible.ToBoolean(provider) ? 1 : 0);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[4])
        return (object) convertible.ToChar(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[5])
        return (object) convertible.ToSByte(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[6])
        return (object) convertible.ToByte(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[7])
        return (object) convertible.ToInt16(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[8])
        return (object) convertible.ToUInt16(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[9])
        return (object) convertible.ToInt32(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[10])
        return (object) convertible.ToUInt32(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[11])
        return (object) convertible.ToInt64(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[12])
        return (object) convertible.ToUInt64(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[13])
        return (object) convertible.ToSingle(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[14])
        return (object) convertible.ToDouble(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[15])
        return (object) convertible.ToDecimal(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[16])
        return (object) convertible.ToDateTime(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[18])
        return (object) convertible.ToString(provider);
      if (runtimeType == Convert.ConvertTypes[1])
        return value;
      else
        return convertible.ToType(conversionType, provider);
    }
  }
}
```

And here's the type array it's using:

```
internal static readonly RuntimeType[] ConvertTypes = new RuntimeType[19]
{
  (RuntimeType) typeof (Empty),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (object),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (DBNull),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (bool),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (char),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (sbyte),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (byte),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (short),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (ushort),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (int),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (uint),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (long),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (ulong),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (float),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (double),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (Decimal),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (DateTime),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (object),
  (RuntimeType) typeof (string)
};
```